# How to get value name array for type file when use formidable?

Tags: node.js, jquery-upload-file-plugin

`<input type="file" class="smart-file" name="images[]"  data-btn-class="btn-primary" data-field-type="bootstrap-file-filed"  multiple>`

`router.post('/introcpn',function(req,res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, file) {
        if(err) throw err;``
        console.log(file.images)
    })
})

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the code manually in node_module/formidable/incoming_form.js :

https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/pull/380/files

This one is not in the master. It will allow you to get value name array